# Is there a more efficient way of manipulating this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This method does exactly what I want (return a copy of params hash, minus a couple) but it seems a little verbose. Is there a more concise implementation?

```
def strip_some_params
  params_copy = params.clone
  params_copy.delete(:param1)
  params_copy.delete(:param2)
  params_copy
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveSupport has [`except`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb):

```
params.except(:param1, :param2)
```

This effectively does the same thing you're doing (iterates through and deletes), but your code becomes more elegant.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

There's always [Hash#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject)

```
def strip_some_params(params)
  params.reject{|key, _| [:param1, :param2].include? key}
end
```